# Existence of a Technic 1M Half Beam

Tags: technic, piece-information

I am building a fidget spinner out of LEGO and need two parts to help it spin better while not being extremely loose. The only part I can think of that would work would be a Technic 1M Half Beam, but I don't know if it exists. Does that piece exist? If so, where can I buy it from? If not, do you know of any piece that would work just as well?

Here is a picture of my WIP:
[image: fidget spinner]
You can see in the middle where there are two spaces that I would like to be filled. Something the height of a tile would fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are seeking a spacer that can spin freely on a Technic axle. Essentially, you want a 1/2 bush that has a round hole rather than an axle hole. I don't believe that this piece exists in Technic.

The old [Technic Hub/Handle (424)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=424#T=C) may do what you want, but it is thicker than a 1/2 bush:

[image: Part 424]

Failing that, a minifig ring may work for what you need if you have one handy:

[image: Frodo with the Ring]

Feel free to post pictures of your WIP and we may be able to provide better suggestions if those don't work.

Edit:

Now that you've posted a photo, I wonder if a 1/2 Bush might just work:

[image: 32123]

Edit2:

I've now had a chance to play around with some alternate designs, and the one that I like best simply replaces the 2x2 plate and 2x2 tile with this wheel hub (3482):

[image: 3482]

This is solid and has a nice feel in the hand. It gives you the flexibility to have this rotate as tightly or loosely as you'd like.

Some [others](https://rebrickable.com/mocs/MOC-8282/Totobricks/lego-fidget-spinner-7/) like to just use an additional 2x2 round plate:

[image: another fidget spinner]

Comment: I added a picture

Comment: That hub would be way too large

Comment: How many tiles thick are those rings?

Comment: The ring is 1 tile thick. I wonder if a half bush would do what you need seeing your photo.

Comment: I have tried using the half bush, but that causes too much friction. I don't know if the ring would be any better

Comment: I don't think the ring is any better. I've updated my answer. I like just using a wheel hub instead of the plates, but I'm not sure how attached you were to that look.

Comment: To keep my design, I may need to use a longer axle and use my 1M (full) Beam.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
A little late, but a round tile with hole exists now.

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15535#T=C